# Is it possible to pull data into R and save the incoming stream directly/simultaneously to hard drive?

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am pulling data from an oracle database into R. The data table is too big (>15gb) and therefore runs the risk of filling the RAM (32gb) too much or crashing the R session forcing me to restart with the process.

Is it possible to run the query on the database and save the incoming data (data being downloaded) directly/simultaneously to the hard drive (.RDS etc)?

Comment: Maybe you're pulling too much datas ? Are all fields required for what you wish to do after ? (writing to disk won't solve any problem here, you may just ask for a csv dump of the table, but that won't solve your crash problem loading too much data in your R session anyway...)

Comment: Which interface are you using? If you are connecting through `ROracle`, you can send your query through `dbSendQuery` and `fetch` as many rows as you want, save them and repeat.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks but i have to pull the entire table for analysis. Don't see an option as of now, at least until I understand how I want to summarize the data.

Comment: @nicola I am using RODBC but I get the hint that I could break the data pull in parts and rbind/cbind later

Comment: "at least until I understand how I want to summarize the data"...While this won't address your actual question, I would advise against pulling the entire data set until you have decided how to approach the analysis.  Work with a subset of the data.  That may required a few queries to make sure you get some of each group, but conceptualizing your analysis will likely be easier and faster using a subset.  Plus, you may find that your analysis can make use of packages like `biglm` that don't require you to pull the entire dataset into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to "page" through rows say 100k at a time with a loop and save each as an .rds like table_1_100000.rds. Once you're through, I'd recommend checking ids (alone) against the database to make sure you got all rows ("checksum" concept).